# Rigid Body Simulation Bake to Keyframes moving all objects to same location

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to bake my physics simulation to keyframes however when I do so all the objects clump together (as shown in photo)

The objects are animated and I have found if I make a single user copy of the animation action for one of the individual objects it fixes the problem. However, as there are over 600 objects it would be too time consuming to do this for each individual objects.

Is there a work around for this?

[image: Objects Clumped together]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I just figured out a solution. I just selected all the objects then went into made each a single using Objects > Relations > Make Single User > I then selected Object animation and object data animation (As pictured)

I hope this can help someone that finds this.

[image: Make single user]

Comment: that's indeed working!